# Add Relationship for Columns with different data Types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, relationship, table-relationships

I have 2 table in my database , master table have a field named "ID" with "uniqueidentifier" data-type , Detail table have a field named "MID" with "nvarchar" Data-Type that I store Master table field "ID" value in it

I want to add a master-detail relationship between these tables but when i want to do , a message says : " The Following data types properties of column "..." do not match column those of "..." "

it`s not possible that i set "MID" data-type to "uniquidentifier" !

in MS-Access it`s possible to do , but how can i do this in MS-SQLServer 2008 ?!

thanks before ...

Comment: Please share the definition of your tables as two `CREATE TABLE` statements. It's much easier to help when we can see the code.

Comment: @isme : there is no code !, I do this with table-designer in SQL Server Managment Studio

Comment: There is always code. The table designer just hides it from you. Find each table in the Object Explorer, right-click, and choose 'Script Table as > CREATE To > New Query Editor Window'. Copy the script for each table into your question.

Comment: "it's not possible that i set `MID` data-type to `uniquidentifier`" - then you can't have a foreign key. Simple as that.

Comment: When you say "it's not possible to do...", do you mean you are trying to do that and it's not working? Or should we understand that you *will not* do that for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this easily, as in SQL Server the column data types have to match for a foreign key to be created. However, there is a (rather nasty and complex) workaround. You can create a foreign key in SQL Server to any column with a UNIQUE constraint on it. So, you can perform the following steps:

**Option 1**

(Better, as suggested in comments)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD ID_Text AS CAST(ID AS varchar(36)) PERSISTED UNIQUE
GO
```

Then you can set a foreign key to this column.

**Option 2**

(My original, less good)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD ID_Text varchar(36) NULL
GO

UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET ID_Text = CAST(ID AS varchar(36))
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ALTER COLUMN ID_Text varchar(36) NOT NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT U_ID_Text UNIQUE (ID_Text)
GO
```

Then, to make sure that `ID_Text` stays populated, you'll need an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on inserts:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TI_Table1_ID_Text
ON dbo.Table1
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

        SET NOCOUNT ON

        INSERT  dbo.Table1
                (ID, ID_Text, OtherFields)
        SELECT  ID, CAST(ID AS varchar(36)), OtherFields
        FROM    inserted

        SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO
```

Here, replace `OtherFields` with ... er ... your other fields.

Then, you can forget about the new `ID_Text` field apart from the fact that you can create a foreign key from your `MID` column to it.

Comment: An even better way would be to make the new column be a computed column. Then he would not need to play around with INSTEAD OF triggers.

Comment: You can't create a foreign key to a computed column.

Comment: You can if the computed column is setup properly: _not nullable_, _unique_ and _persisted_. Tested it and it worked (Sql server 2008)

Comment: Persisted is the key, yes. Presume we were all going for not nullable and unique in the circumstances anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom constraint. First, create a function that checks your constraint.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_CheckCustomConstraint
(
    @ForeignKeyValue nvarchar
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result bit
    SELECT @Result = CONVERT(bit, COUNT(*))
    FROM MasterTable
    WHERE ID = @ForeignKeyValue

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Then create the constraint on the foreign key table.

```
ALTER TABLE [DetailTable]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [ConstraintName] CHECK ([udf_CheckCustomConstraint]([MID])=(1))
```

Hope this helps.